# Error LNK1194 when using delay-load and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, dll

Question for VS 2019 (community). I have a linker error that I cannot find on [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-errors-and-warnings?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DFR-FR%26k%3Dk(LNK1194)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-160).

I have 3 DLLs built with Qt and with the dependencies: **a.dll** imports **b.dll**, **b.dll** imports **c.dll** (not the real file names but I do not think it matters). All 3 DLLs have multiple classes derived from `QObject`, with the `Q_OBJECT` macro in them, hence with a `staticMetaObject`. In terms of dependencies to the Qt DLL, it goes by increasing complexity, that is:

- **c.dll** only depends on `Qt6Core`
- **b.dll** depends on `Qt6Core`, `Qt6Gui` and `Qt6Widgets`
- **a.dll** depends on `Qt6Core`, `Qt6Gui`, `Qt6Widgets`, `Qt6Charts` and `Qt6Svg`.

I can compile **a.dll** so that it delays the load of **b.dll**. I am sure it does indeed delay it because without that option, I see during debug that loading **a.dll** fails.

Originally, this is not how I wanted to configure the compilation. My goal was to delay the loading of **c.dll** when compiling **b.dll**. However, when I do so, the linker returns a `LNK1194` fatal error, for both Debug and Release compilations:

```
Cannot delay-load c.dll due to import of data symbol '"__declspec(dllimport) public: static struct QMetaObject const QSTrade::staticMetaObject" (__imp_?staticMetaObject@QSTrade@@2UQMetaObject@@B)'
```

*My VS is not in English but I guess that would be the exact text it would give me if it was.*

That `QSTrade` class is declared as (with `C_EXPORT` being `Q_DECL_EXPORT`/`Q_DECL_IMPORT`):

```
class C_EXPORT QSTrade : public QSHolding, public std::enable_shared_from_this<QSTrade>, public QSObject<QSTrade> {
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(int64_t          ID                      READ id)
/// Some more Q_PROPERTY, followed by normal class members
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSTrade*)
```

I do not have the beginning of a clue of what is going on here. **c.dll** has more classes with a `staticMetaObject` member (53 vs 24) and depends on fewer Qt modules (1 vs 3, see above) than **b.dll**. AFAICT, both are compiled with the same options (at least I have spotted no discrepancies in the many, many options when I double-checked).

- What explains I can delay-load **b.dll** but not **c.dll**?
  It does not feel `staticMetaObject` is the actual reason since it actually works for one of them.
- Optional question: would the linker only report 1 class for error `LNK1194`?
  In other words, does is somehow affects only the `QSTrade` class or is there a chance it affects all classes in **c.dll** (but only `QSTrade` gets reported)?